# smtproutes relay all except local virtual domains

Tags: smtp, qmail

I'm using smtproutes to deliver users' email to certain domains through an external SMTP server with example.com:externalsmtp.com

How can I deliver all the emails to my external SMTP except for local virtual domains?

Answer (score 0):

See the manpage `qmail-remote(8)`, [Control Files](https://manned.org/qmail-remote/012725a8#head6):

> **smtproutes**
>
> Artificial SMTP routes.  Each route has the form `domain:relay`,
> without any extra spaces.  If `domain` matches *host*, qmail-remote will
> connect to `relay`, as if *host* had `relay` as its only MX.  (It will
> also avoid doing any `CNAME` lookups on *recip*.)  *host* may include a
> colon and a port number to use instead of the normal SMTP port, 25:
>
> ```
> inside.af.mil:firewall.af.mil:26
> ```
>
> `relay` may be empty; this tells qmail-remote to look up `MX` records as
> usual.  smtproutes may include *wildcards*:
>
> ```
> .af.mil:
> :heaven.af.mil
> ```
>
> Here any address ending with `.af.mil` (but not `af.mil` itself) is
> routed by its `MX` records; any other address is artificially routed
> to `heaven.af.mil`.

This doesn't state it directly, but the `domain` can be empty, too, which works as a wildcard. Therefore, you can specify a *smart host* relay, as explained e.g. by Dave Sill in *Life with qmail*: [3.2.4. Relaying to a smart host](http://www.lifewithqmail.com/lwq.html#smarthost-relay).

```
echo ":smtp.example.com" > /var/qmail/control/smtproutes
```

So, if you would like to relay everything but `example.net` and `example.org` through the smart host:

```
example.net:
example.org:mail.example.org
:smtp.example.com
```

Here,

- mail to `example.net` will look for the MX records (empty `relay´),
- mail to `example.org` will go through `mail.example.org`, and
- everything else will go through the smart host `smtp.example.com` (empty i.e. wildcard `domain`).